# Why doesn't this trigger work when SelectionUnit="Cell"

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want a button to be enabled only when a cell in a DataGrid is selected.

This line of XAML works when the DataGrid's SelectionUnit is set to "FullRow" :

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"
```

It no longer properly enables the button when the SelectionUnit of the DataGrid is set to "Cell"

Any idea why this is happening?

Are there any work good work-arounds?

Thanks

Comment: What about `IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedCells.Count}"`?

Comment: Neither works..

Comment: Does `SelectedCells.Count` have a nonzero value when cells are selected? If it does, you can give the Button a Style with a DataTrigger that disables the button when `{Binding ElementName=dataGrid, Path=SelectedCells.Count}` evaluates to zero. Alternatively, you could write an integer-to-bool [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, just checked. It is properly updating the count. I will just use a normal data trigger. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid's `SelectedCells.Count` should return a nonzero value when the DataGrid is selecting by Cells. A [`DataTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) in a Style on the `Button` can bind to that and disable the button when `Value="0"`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the SelectedCells.Count property of a DataGrid does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

My binding was not able to notify my data trigger when the number of selected cells changed, and the data trigger value was always 0 (even though the code-behind showed otherwise)...

I ended up binding my data trigger to an internal property that tracked the selected row index of the DataGrid, and checked for it to be equal to -1.

```
           <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedRowIndex}" Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
```